# Cannot find symbol in extended class

Tags: java, package, extends

Hello I have two classes into the package "pack3"
One is the extension of the other one.
The "Up" class is:

```
package pack3;

public class Up{
int k=1;
public String toString(){
    return String.valueOf(k);
    }
 }
```

The "Down" class is:
    package pack3;

```
public class Down extends Up{
int k=2;

public String toString(){
    return k+", "+super.ToString();
    }
 }
```

I have this error on the shell:
    Down.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
        return k+", "+super.ToString();
                           ^
    symbol: method ToString()
    1 error

Comment: Typos all over. Also, fields are not polymorphic.

Comment: `Down extends Up`? That is an a bit weird inheritance. Maybe better `Up extends Direction` and `Down extends Direction`

Comment: super.ToString(); should be super.toString(); . The "t" should not be capitalized.

Comment: Up and Down are the Class names. I translated from my language in English

Comment: Well that's an awfully blocky lookin T you have there...even the compiler told you that! (Check that your case sensitivity is ok to start with.

Comment: @Solace Oh yes that one is the error...Thank you very much!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return k+", "+super.ToString();
```

it should be super.toString();

I hope this help.